# How to extract specific id number from a array of buttons in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When I run the code below, it generates a table of columns ID, Product, Price and a column with buttons "edit" and another with "delete". When I debug this program via var_dump(), I get a output of e.g.:
array(1) { [30]=> string(6) "Delete" } or array(1) { [27]=> string(6) "Delete" } with the number in the [] corresponding the the products ID. For the edit column, instead of "Delete" it says "Edit". **My Question is, how do I extract the information outputs button 17(corresponding with ID number) of button "Edit" has been clicked?**

```
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
        echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Product</th> <th>Price ($)</th> <th>Edit Menu</th> <th>Delete Menu</th> </tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
          echo "<tr>";     // echo out the contents of each row into a table
          echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
          echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" name="id1['.$row['id'].']" />' . '</td>';
          echo '<td><input type="submit" value="Delete" name="id2['.$row['id'].']" />' . '</td>';
          echo "</tr>";
          }
          // close table>
          echo "</table>";
          echo '</form>';

          if(isset($_POST['id1'])) {
            var_dump($_POST['id1']);
          }

          if(isset($_POST['id2'])) {
            var_dump($_POST['id2']);
          }
```

Comment: What is button 17? Pls explain it more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to php and I'm still learning haha! Since each button is assigned name="id1['.$row['id'].']", I want a int value of 17 if button in row 17 is pressed. Thanks.

Comment: You might want `$_POST['id1'][17]` - you've set the index by ID (`value="Edit" name="id1['.$row['id'].']"`)

Comment: $_POST['id1'][16] chooses the 17th item in the array, but I want the value to change whenever I press a button in different columns. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Peter its a table with buttons edit and delete buttons? If its, why you need to send values with post? Normal link with GET is satisfied.

Comment: `$edit_id = array_flip($_POST)['Edit']` should do the job. It gives a string `"id1[17]"` You could generate some name which is simpler to parse.

Comment: [link](imgur.com/a/ifuNe). This is what my program looks like. It's multiple buttons in a column. So what I want to do is extract which button in which row was clicked. And at the buttom is the var_dump() output. Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` dumps the entire `$_POST` array. You can see, what you get. There will be 1 or 0 array items containing "Edit" as value. try `var_dump(array_flip($_POST))` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

First you **name** button like what you need eg. update, delete etc..
Then you can handle it with **POST name**.
Last you can get your ID by **Key** from array.

```
   <?php
    // id list or your source
    $array = [1,2,3];

    // handle edit button with id
    if(isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        var_dump('--- edit');
        var_dump(key($_POST['btnEdit'])); die;
    }

    // handle delete button with id    
    if(isset($_POST['btnDelete'])) {
        var_dump('--- delete');
        var_dump(key($_POST['btnDelete'])); die;
    }
    ?>
```

and your HTML table:

```
<?php foreach($array as $id) { ?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <?php echo $id; ?> |
    <input type=submit name="btnEdit[<?php echo $id; ?>]" value="edit">
    <input type=submit name="btnDelete[<?php echo $id; ?>] "value="delete">
</form>

<?php } ?>
```